# Saving a GIF image in R

Tags: r

I generate a GIF image with this code:

```
library(animation)

saveGIF({
  for(i in 2:416)
  {
    data<-c(MatrixY[,i])
    x.specA<-spectrum(data,plot=FALSE)
    print(paste(i))
    z<-matrix(x.specA$spec,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
    persp(x,y,z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
  }
},
movie.name = "test.gif", 
interval = 0.1, 
ani.width = 500, 
ani.height = 500,)
```

Is it possible to save this gif image on hard disk?

Comment: The code you're providing should have saved a file called test.gif in your working directory. See `?saveGIF`.

Comment: Note however that you need to have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed.